# cassandra backup files smaller than original

Tags: cassandra, backup, nodetool

I am trying to do a backup of all my data from Cassandra, in order to move them to a different machine.

I've been using nodetool to do this.

```
nodetool -h localhost snapshot -t my_backup keyspcace
```

After running nodetool, a new 'snapshot' folder gets created inside the folder of each column family, and that folder contains a folder named 'my_backup'. However, the size of this folder is rather small (under 10% of the size of the original folder). I've copied that folder onto my machine, stopped Cassandra, replaced the files inside each keyspace and started Cassandra back up.

However, now when I do a

```
select count(*) from something
```

I get a smaller number of entries than was on the original server.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I make a full backup of the data inside Cassandra in order to move them to a different machine?

Comment: What is your replication factor and cluster size?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. At the moment, Cassandra runs on only one machine. So cluster size = 1,  Replication factor = 1.

Comment: What Cassandra version do you use?

Comment: Using Cassandra 2.0.8.       I just tried doing nodetool flush -- keyspace and it seems to be getting all of the information now(tested on a smaller, testing database). However, why are the backup files so small compared to the files in the original folders? For a 4GB folder, I am getting a 114MB backup.(for the 4GB version I could not determine if all of my entries are present in the backup)